# Is it possible to resize or reduce resolution to reduce file's size with jquery /js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to resize or reduce resolution to reduce file's size with jquery /js ? In my html, I have form to upload multiple image like this :

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-12">
     <label for="file">Upload Foto</label>
     <input name="file[]" id="file" class="btn btn-primary" type="file" multiple >
</div>

<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="upload">Upload</button>
```

I want to create image resize berfore upload using ajax. Here is the jquery code.

```
$(document).on('submit', '#upload', function () {
  var inputFile = $('input#file');
  var filesToUpload = inputFile[0].files;

if (filesToUpload.length > 0) {
     // provide the form data that would be sent to sever through ajax
     var formData = new FormData();

     for (var i = 0; i < filesToUpload.length; i++) {
          // Do something to resize image or reduce resolution for minimize delay upload
          var file = filesToUpload[i];
          formData.append("file[]", file, file.name);
     }

        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url('surveyor/c_surveyor/add_file_image/'); ?>/" + NO_TANK + EIR_REF,
            type: 'post',
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function () {
                   $(":file").val('');
                   $(":text").val('');
                   $("#tableClean").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
                   $("#tableReport").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
                   $('#pilih_isotank').after('<div class="callout callout-success lead" id="div_error"><p id="pesan_error">Semua Data Berhasil Terupload</p></div>');
                   $('#div_error').fadeIn("fast");
                   $('#pesan_error').html(obj.Message);
                   $('#div_error').fadeOut(7000);
             }
     });
```

Comment: It's probably doable with a canvas and a lot of work, but this is something that is usually done serverside as it's so much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with jQuery. Maybe with canvas as *adeneo* mentioned, but that's a lot of work. Don't do it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10545724)

Comment: But the question is "is it possible ..?", so that's a yes/no question, and the answer is no. Right?

Comment: Well your final answer is "maybe with canvas". If it can be done with canvas, it can be done. You say that it can't be done, then you say that it might be possible. That doesn't sound like a yes or no answer to me

Comment: Well, I meant "yes it is possible with canvas, but it's not worth doing it". It's not a may be. I'll update my answer if that satisfies you, but I can't think of any other possible answer for that question. I believe that if a question can't be answered, it's an issue in the question itself, not the answer. Yet I don't see any problem with the question as it doesn't violate any community standard.